# Is there an external parser generator tool used for building Alloy language parser

Tags: parser-generator, alloy

Have Alloy developers used any parser generator tool (like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)) for parsing alloy specifications, or is its parser built-in and specifically written for the alloy language purpose?

If they used external tool for Alloy parser implementation, how can I access further information regarding this (for example the grammar which is fed into the external parser generator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alloy uses a modified version of CUP (which is shipped with the Alloy distribution).  You can find the grammar specification files (`Alloy.lex` and `Alloy.cup`) inside the `edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.parser` package.  In the same package there are some bash scripts used to generate corresponding lexer/parser classes.

Answer (score 0):

http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/book-chapters/alloy-language-reference.pdf

Section B.3 has the grammar.

Can't say anything about the language implementation.